# Dixson's "Graded Exercises in English" - answers..?

Tags: grammar, learning, teaching

I've been looking for the answers of the classic, best-seller "Graded Exercises in English", by Robert J. Dixson. Please, was it published somewhere, somehow? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It was originally published in 1943, but apparently there was [a "revised" edition published in China](https://www.worldcat.org/title/graded-exercises-in-english-for-the-foreign-born-with-key-answers/oclc/373679160?referer=di&ht=edition) in 1967 by "Taipei : Wen hua tu shu gong si..."  Searching in Google Books for "**Graded Exercises in English**" in Google Books, I see that most of the results are flagged "No preview", which probably means the copyright holder hasn't authorised GB to scan / display the full text (maybe they never authorised that Chinese revision/reprint either).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a request for resources